# Scroll animations not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T33NN_pPeNI) tutorial on coding scrolling animations, yet when the author's code displays animations (at 3:48), my code displays nothing.

The issue being that the `hidden` class sets `opacity: 0`, and the observer never manages to observe the sections, so the class `show` which sets `opacity: 1` is never added.

---

```
<template>
  <section class="hidden">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </section>
  <section class="hidden">
    <h2>More text</h2>
  </section>
</template>

<style scoped>
* {
  background-color: 131313;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>

<script>
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    console.log(entry);
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove("show");
    }
  });
});

const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
</script>
```

---

**Edit:** I should have noted that I'm using Vue, and the code I've included above is the precisely what's written in my App.vue file.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem. Could you make your code into a runnable snippet and test it shows the problem? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I do not know how to make this into a runnable snippet that uses Vue (as opposed to simply JS, CSS, and HTML).

Comment: Hmmm, are you saying that vue somehow deals with IntersectionObserver differently from pure JS?

Comment: @AHaworth apparently, although I've seen others use the IntersectionObserver in Vue in a very similar manner to what I'm attempting. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dozWGIgCWF8