# Unable to use IntersectionObserver in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

By now I must have tried dozen different codes -with no avail- to make Vue work with IntersectionObserver.

The code below displays displays nothing. **What changes can I make so that sections become visible when they intersect the viewport?**

---

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <section class="hidden">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </section>
  <section class="hidden">
    <h2>More text</h2>
  </section>
</template>

<style scoped>
* {
  background-color: 131313;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>

<script setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue";

onMounted(() => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      console.log(entry);
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        entry.target.classList.add("show");
      } else {
        entry.target.classList.remove("show");
      }
    });
  });

  const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
  hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
});
</script>
```

This is a follow-up to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76358437/scroll-animations-not-working-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems to mostly work but that's not how we do things in Vue. In Vue you should use [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) to reference components instead of using querySelector and you should also [use refs to change classes](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html) in the template instead of directly modifying the DOM yourself (vue's reactivity system can't track the changes you make manually yourself and might overwrite them at any moment). To make all of the above easier we will need to make the section it's own component.

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div style="height: 1000px; background: red"></div>
  <Section>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </Section>
  <Section>
    <h2>More text</h2>
  </Section>
</template>

<style scoped>
* {
  background-color: 131313;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
</style>

<script setup>
import Section from './Section.vue'

</script>
```

Section.vue:

```
<template>
  <section class="hidden" :class="{show}" ref="section">
    <slot></slot>
  </section>
</template>

<style sciped>
section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  background: blue;
}
</style>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
  
const section = ref(null);
const show = ref(false);

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    console.log(entry);
    show.value = entry.isIntersecting;
  });
});

onMounted(() => observer.observe(section.value));
</script>
```

Live demo: [Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

In the example I also used the [isIntersecting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry/isIntersecting) property to determine if the element is intersecting instead of using the ratio.

Comment: Can this observer be inverse? Like, If `hero section` is not visible, add a class to header component?

Comment: @AdrianoCahete Yeah, you can check for `!entry.isIntersecting` and emit an event from the section component